# Get Unique Users by Date

Tags: sql, hive

I'm using a 3rd party analytics system that uses Hive. Basically, given an events table (evt)

```
userID (s) | date (UTC_timestamp) | monthCluster (month)
```

I'd like to return a list of unique userIDs by dates in the month. So for the month of November, the output would look like:

```
      Date | userID 
2013-11-01 | 000000
2013-11-01 | 000001
2013-11-02 | 000000
2013-11-02 | 000002
```

I can't exactly use

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(utc_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), DISTINCT(s)
FROM evt
WHERE month = 201311
group by FROM_UNIXTIME(utc_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

'cause Distinct and group by don't exactly play nice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it can't be used that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the distinct and adding s to the group by should give you unique results for "s" per date:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(utc_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), s
FROM evt
WHERE month = 201311
group by FROM_UNIXTIME(utc_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), s
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a spaz; I appreciate it.